# Javascript & Html loads twice (form field) how can I know which element it belongs to?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**HTML**:

The field below is being loaded dynamically, more than once.

```
<div>
<label><?php echo $form->label; ?>
<select 
       name=<?php echo $form->name; ?>
       idx=<?php echo $form->entity; ?>
>
<option value="<?php echo $form->option()->value; ?>"><?php echo $form->option()->name; ?></option>
</select>

<td>
<a href="#" id="addnew"  onclick="onOffButton('addfield', 'addbtn'); return false;">[Open] Add New</a>

<span id="addfield">
   <input name="newstuff type="text"></input>
</span>

<a href="#do-something" id="addbtn">Click to add</a>
</td>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

I can make the script below load twice, or once. If I load it once, then it only works for the first field. If I load it twice, then it only works for the second field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onix = false;
    function onOffButton(id, text) {

        var select_id = $("#addfield").prevAll('select').attr("idx");
        console.log(select_id);

        if (onix == false) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(text).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("addnew").textContent="[Close] Add New";
            onix = true;                   
        } else if (onix == true) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(text).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("addnew").textContent="[Open] Add New";
            onix = false;                
        }
    }
</script>
```

**SUMMARY**

I need to know which element the section addfield belongs to. Most importantly, the form->entity. The goal is to generate a GET link like so: `localhost/$form->entity/create/[value-of-newstuff]`

**I tried** setting an array on an external file. And that does work, but I don't know what to do with it.

**I also tried** using `<?php echo rand(); ?>` on all of the attributes. The results were as expected, when javascript loads once it only works for the first field, loads twice, only works for the second field.

How can I overcome this obstacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved it for now**

In a very crude way, there's probably a more beautiful way, but this is what I came up with to solve it.

Basically I started the field with:

```
<?php $onix = rand(); ?>
```

Then I slapped that crap on every id of the html. On the javascript side I slapped it basically everywhere. It's ugly as a mofo but it works like a charm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onix<?php echo $onix; ?> = false;
    function onOffButton<?php echo $onix; ?>(id<?php echo $onix; ?>, text<?php echo $onix; ?>) {

        var select_id<?php echo $onix; ?> = $("#addfield<?php echo $onix; ?>").prevAll('select').attr("idx<?php echo $onix; ?>");
        console.log(select_id<?php echo $onix; ?>);

        if (onix<?php echo $onix; ?> == false) {
            document.getElementById(id<?php echo $onix; ?>).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(text<?php echo $onix; ?>).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("addnew<?php echo $onix; ?>").textContent="[Close] Add New";
            onix<?php echo $onix; ?> = true;                   
        } else if (onix<?php echo $onix; ?> == true) {
            document.getElementById(id<?php echo $onix; ?>).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(text<?php echo $onix; ?>).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("addnew<?php echo $onix; ?>").textContent="[Open] Add New";
            onix<?php echo $onix; ?> = false;                
        }
    }
</script>
```